# EXC_BAD_ACCESS in [FBSession dealloc] after deleting app from Facebook

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

My app uses Facebook to share and post likes. It works fine until I delete app from Facebook via Settings -> Apps.

The use case is the following: I authorize on Facebook via my app, do any social actions, keep app opened, delete app from Apps on Facebook, try to do like or share again.

Then the login dialog appears and in 50% of cases app crashes on `[FBSession dealloc]` (on *Thread 1*, as shown in Navigator). The stack trace looks like this:

```
0x141718:  blx    0x850a90                  ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
0x14171c:  movw   r0, #0x5586
0x141720:  mov    r1, r5
0x141722:  movt   r0, #0x92
0x141726:  add    r0, pc
0x141728:  ldr    r0, [r0]
0x14172a:  ldr    r0, [r4, r0]
0x14172c:  blx    0x850a90                  ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
0x141730:  movw   r0, #0x557a <<< EXC_BAD_ACCESS
```

It turns out, that before crash `FBSession` is in the `FBSessionClosed` state. I have a precaution method, which checks for this right before opening a new session and clears the old session like this:

```
  FBSession* session = [FBSession activeSession];
  [session closeAndClearTokenInformation];
  [session close];
  [FBSession setActiveSession:nil];
```

Then I open a new session with the following method

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_actions", @"user_likes"]
                                   defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                                        allowLoginUI:YES
                                   completionHandler: ... ]
```

and have a crash.

Could anyone tell how to fix this problem?

Thanks.

LATE UPDATE.
It turned out that I deallocated some NSString object in my code twice. So the trouble is not relative to Facebook iOS client library.
Be safe around MRR, guys.

Comment: For now I just gave up with the idea to re-login the user if he deleted app from Facebook. Just let him to do any social actions and inform that there was an error.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest check once with Instruments Tool, you will have a clear picture why and where exactly it is crashing.